# Erro ao tentar listar objetos que estão no banco de dados ao utilizar Foreach();

Tags: php, mysql, select

Estou fazendo esse código para capturar os elementos de uma tabela no meu banco de dados porém ao executar o código **foreach** recebo o erro e não sei oque fazer

Função para buscar os dados:

```
function listaUniformes($conexao) {
$uniformes = array();
$query = "select * from uniformes";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
while($uniforme = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    array_push($uniformes, $uniforme);
}
return $uniforme;
```

}

Foreach :

```
<?php
                listaUniformes($conexao);
                 foreach($uniformes as $uniforme) {
                    ?>
                     <tr>
                         <?= $uniforme['nome']; ?>
                     </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

Erro quando entro na página

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\warehouse\uniformes.php on line 21
```

Comment: Qual erro é? aparece alguma mensagem?

Comment: Qual seria o erro?

Comment: Adicionado na publicação

Comment: `$uniforme` não é um array, da um `print_r()` nele antes do return.

Comment: adicionei  o print_r($uniforme) na function e erro persiste

Comment: Mostrou um array em branco?

Comment: Não, não mudou nada

Comment: Faltou atribuir, faça assim `$uniformes = listaUniformes($conexao);`

Comment: Pronto, adicionei esse código antes do foreach , meu Ide tirou o highlight informando um erro porém a página continua informando o erro do Foreach

Comment: o array_push é uma função? Onde Retorna?

Comment: Adicionei o array_push na função que captura os produtos no banco de dados para enfiar o que foi atribuido pela variável $uniforme ao array $uniformes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua função retorna o valor errado deveria retornar `$uniformes` e não `$uniforme`

Mude:

```
return $uniforme;
```

Para:

```
return $uniforme;
```

Lembre de criar uma variável ou passar um array para o foreach, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
   foreach(listaUniformes($conexao) as $uniforme) {
```

Ou:

```
<?php
   $arr = listaUniformes($conexao);
   foreach($arr as $uniforme) {
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mas fiquei com uma dúvida, se a função ja retorna $uniformes por que  eu não posso colocar foreach($uniformes as $uniforme)?

Comment: @LuhanSalimena a função não retorna nenhuma variável por padrão são sempre valores. Depois que a função acaba todas as variáveis declaradas dentro dela são desalocadas ou seja passam a  não existir mais. Nesse caso vc pega o retorno (valor) e a atribui em uma nova variável que está fora do escopo da função.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado :D